# Running Parse Server with MongoDB on Digital Ocean

Tags: ios, mongodb, parse-platform, digital-ocean

I am one of the developers that have been using Parse as a backend for an iOS app and am now in trouble, because of Facebook shutting the service down. After investigating possible solutions and [migrating options](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Migrating-an-Existing-Parse-App), I have decided to go for [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com) to run the open source [Parse Server](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server) and host my MongoDB there.

As the solution is getting more popular, with amazing guide-throughs popping up  every day (like [the one](http://julienrenaux.fr/2016/01/29/complete-parse-server-migration-guide/) by Julien Renaux), I wanted to ask whether there are any known shortcommings or issues you have encountered after implementing such a solution or along the way?

Thank you